# Is AMD Opteron 2382 2.6GHz comptabile with supermicro H8DME-2?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Is AMD Opteron 2382 2.6GHz comptabile with supermicro H8DME-2?

Anyone knows?

Comment: You might want to read http://www.supermicro.com/aplus/motherboard/opteron2000/mcp55/h8dme-2.cfm and http://products.amd.com/pages/OpteronCPUDetail.aspx?id=492&f1=&f2=&f3=Yes&f4=&f5=&f6=&f7=&f8=&f9=&f10=&f11=& we expect a certain level of research before asking a question here at Superuser.  The motherboard supports the `Socket F ( 1207 )` socket.

Comment: I did read that, but I wasn't sure completely if it was compatible. You are assuming by reading everyone should understand it.

Comment: You are right.  I believe with a topic like this, if properly researched, it would understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://www.supermicro.com/aplus/motherboard/opteron2000/mcp55/h8dme-2.cfm)

Key Features

1. Two Six-Core / Quad-Core / Dual-Core
   AMD Opteron™ 2000 Series (Socket F)
   support; HT3.0 Link support ^
2. nVidia® MCP55 Pro Chipset,
   NEC uPD720400
3. Up to 128GB DDR2 800/667/533 
   SDRAM; 16 DIMM Sockets
4. Dual-port Gigabit
   LAN/Ethernet Controller
5. 6 SATA2 3.0Gb/s HDD Support
6. 2 x8 PCI-e,
   2 64-bit 133/100MHz PCI-X,
   2 64-bit 100MHz PCI-X
7. ATI ES1000 Graphics
8. 8 Fan Support with Speed Control

Being that the 2382 is a Socket F 2000 series, it is compatible with the specs.